# DX12: Is there a way to extract any information from a PSO?

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, directx-12

I'm pretty new to PSOs. I was wondering if there is a way to extract a D3D12_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_STATE_DESC structure for example, holding the info for a particular PSO? Or if there is any way really to access any information from a PipelineStateObject? Or does a PSO become a black box once first created?

Comment: Unlike ID3D12Resource where there is GetDesc method, there is nothing similar for PSOs. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once created, a PSO becomes a black box, you can't retrieve any info about it anymore.

The only thing your can retrieve is the "binary blob" by calling :

```
pso->GetCachedBlob
```

Which allows you to save it to disk (so you can create it back using the cached version, which is faster).

Please note that this blob is Hardware AND Driver dependent.